# How to save() with a particular variable name

Tags: r

I am repeatedly applying a function to read and process a bunch of csv files. Each time it runs, the function creates a data frame (`this.csv.data`) and uses save() to write it to a `.RData` file with a unique name. Problem is, later when I read these `.RData` files using `load()`, the loaded variable names are not unique, because each one loads with the name `this.csv.data`....

I'd like to save them with unique tags so that they come out properly named when I `load()` them. I've created the following code to illustrate .

```
this.csv.data = list(data=c(1:9), unique_tag = "some_unique_tag")
assign(this.csv.data$unique_tag,this.csv.data$data)
# I want to save the data, 
# with variable name of <unique_tag>, 
# at a file named <unique_tag>.dat
saved_file_name <- paste(this.csv.data$unique_tag,"RData",sep=".")
save(get(this.csv.data$unique_tag), saved_file_name)
```

but the last line returns:

> ```
> "Error in save(get(this_unique_tag), file = data_tag) : 
>   object ‘get(this_unique_tag)’ not found"
> ```

even though the following returns the data just fine:

```
get(this.csv.data$unique_tag)
```

Comment: I think you  could also take a look at the `envir` argument in `load()` to retain the original column names if they are important. If you don't need to process multiple files at one time, couldn't you `rm()` the object after your analysis before moving on to the next file?

Comment: @Chase, the column names still seem to come out fine, it's the duplicated names of the created dataframes that was the issue. In the long run I anticipate rbinding these data frames into one big one and as you suggest it may be I don't need them more than one at a time.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just name the arguments you use. With your code the following works fine:

```
save(list = this.csv.data$unique_tag, file=saved_file_name)
```

Comment: It "works" in that it doesn't return an error, but when I load(saved_file_name) it creates a variable called "whattosave" instead of "unique_tag" After loading ten files, I would only have the latest "whattosave" instead of ten unique variables...

Comment: @jonw - sorry I was too inattentive. I edited my answer, hope it will really work!

Comment: @jonw; Hey,shouldn't you be giving darczig the answer check?

Answer (score 28):

My preference is to avoid the name in the RData file on load:

```
obj = local(get(load('myfile.RData')))
```

This way you can load various RData files and name the objects whatever you want, or store them in a list etc.

Comment: That'd be nice to explain what `local` and `get` do.

Answer (score 16):

You really should use saveRDS/readRDS to serialize your objects. 
save and load are for saving whole environments.

```
saveRDS(this.csv.data, saved_file_name)
# later
mydata <- readRDS(saved_file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
save.image("myfile.RData")
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
env <- new.env()
env[[varname]] <- object_to_save
save(list=c(varname), envir=env, file='out.Rda')
```

You could probably do it without a new env (but I didn't try this):

```
.GlobalEnv[[varname]] <- object_to_save
save(list=c(varname), envir=.GlobalEnv, file='out.Rda')
```

You might even be able to remove the `envir` variable.