# save an R dataframe with the name specified by a string

Tags: r

On this awesome forum I saw a post which shows how to convert a string to a variable and assign a data frame to that variable. For example:

x = "thisisthestring"

```
# df is a data frame
assign(x, df) # This will assign data frame df to variable thisisthestring
```

What I want to do is save this data frame with the name `thisisthestring`. However, if I try

```
assign(x, df)
save(x, file='somefilename.rda')
```

the file just contains a string "thisisthestring" and not the data frame df.

I also tried

```
save(assign(x, df), file = 'somefile.rda'))
```

That does not work either. Any suggestions how I can save the data frame to a file, where the name of the data frame is specified by the string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to save() with a particular variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675755/how-to-save-with-a-particular-variable-name)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add `x` to the `list`argument from `save()`. From the help file:

> list   A character vector containing
>   the names of objects to be saved.

```
save(list=x, file='somefilename.rda')
```

Comment: Perfect and elegant solution. This is really useful especially when dealing with datasets in custom functions!

Answer (score 6):

You want to pass `x` as the argument `list` to the `save()` function, not as part of argument `...` (the first argument of `save()`). This should work:

```
save(list = x, file='somefilename.rda')
```