# Save object using variable with object name

Tags: r, save

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to save() with a particular variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675755/how-to-save-with-a-particular-variable-name)

I'm wondering what an easy way is to save an object in R, using a variable `objectName` with the name of the object to be saved. I want this to easy save objects, with their name in the file name.

I tried to use `get`, but I didn't manage to save the object with it's original object name.

**Example:**

If I have the object called "temp", which I want to save in the directory "dataDir". I put the name of the object in the variable "objectName".

*Attempt 1:*

```
objectName<-"temp"
save(get(objectName), file=paste(dataDir, objectName, ".RData", sep=""))
load(paste(dataDir, objectName, ".RData", sep=""))
```

This didn't work, because R tries to save an object called `get(objectName)`, instead of the result of this call. So I tried the following:

*Attempt 2:*

```
objectName<-"temp"
object<-get(objectName)
save(object, file=paste(dataDir, objectName, ".RData", sep=""))
load(paste(dataDir, objectName, ".RData", sep=""))
```

This obviously didn't work, because R saves the object with name "object", and not with name "temp". After loading I have a copy of "object", instead of "temp". (Yes, with the same contents...but that is not what I want :) ). So I thought it should be something with pointers. So tried the following:

*Attempt 3:*

```
objectName<-"temp"
object<<-get(objectName)
save(object, file=paste(dataDir, objectName, ".RData", sep=""))
load(paste(dataDir, objectName, ".RData", sep=""))
```

Same result as attempt 2. But I'm not sure I'm doing what I think I'm doing.

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try `save(list=objectName, file=paste(objectName, '.Rdata', sep='') )`.

The key is that the `list` argument to `save` takes a list of character strings that is the names of the objects to save (rather than the actual objects passed through `...`).

Comment: You may also use `paste0(objectName, '.RData')`, which will save you a couple of strokes.

Answer (score 1):

I found your examples hard to understand, but I can think of two possibilities of what you want. You either want the filename to be saved as `objectName.RData` or `temp.RData`. Here is how you do both:

```
objectName<-"temp"

# This saves the object as "temp.RData"
save(objectName, file=paste(dataDir, objectName, ".RData", sep=""))
# Loading it will bring it back with the name objectName, and the value temp
load(paste(dataDir, 'temp', '.RData', sep=''))

# This saves the object as "objectName.RData"
save(objectName, file=paste(dataDir, deparse(substitute(objectName)), ".RData",    sep=""))
# Loading it will bring it back with the name objectName, and the value temp
load(paste(dataDir, 'objectName', '.RData', sep=''))
```

All of your attempts return an error because you called the `get` incorrectly. It should have been `get('objectName')`, but if you think about it, that would get you exactly the same thing as `objectName`.

Comment: Hmm...I think my examples where not clear enough. It is not that I want to save the object "ObjectName", but the object called "temp". For instance; "temp" is a `data.frame` I want to save. Then I want to just do `objectName <- "temp"` and run for example the 'save' code line. (The reason is that I only have to change the value for object name, and all the save & load code (and some other stuff) do not need to change)