# Can convert a string to an object but can't save() it -- why?

Tags: r

I'm trying to process some data frames in a loop and saving the end product date frame under a unique name in a unique file. It works fine but I can't save the final data frame, and I don't understand why.

```
for(meas.name in these.measures) {

...
    assign(paste0(meas.name, "_meas"), peeps)
    save(eval(as.name(paste0(meas.name, "_meas")))), file=paste0("Rdata_files/", meas.name, ".Rdata"))
}
```

For some reason I can't `save()` the data set like this. I get this message:

```
object 'eval(as.name(paste0(meas.name, "_meas")))' not found
```

I get the same message if I use `get(paste0(meas.name, "_meas"))`

However, if I do

```
 str(get(paste0(meas.name, "_meas")))
```

or

```
str(eval(as.name(paste0(meas.name, "_meas"))))
```

it shows this:

```
'data.frame':   1373 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ entry  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ measure: num  0.33 4.73 7.1 2.27 7.1 7.1 7.1 4.73 7.1 7.1 ...
 $ status : int  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
...
```

Shouldn't I be able to `save()` a data frame like this? I don't get it. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675755/how-to-save-with-a-particular-variable-name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084395/save-object-using-variable-with-object-name

Comment: Forget that `assign` exists and learn to use lists instead.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. `save(list=objname, ...` solved my problem!