# Writing files with different( unique) name

Tags: r, writetofile

**Possible Duplicate:** [how to save() with a particular variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675755/how-to-save-with-a-particular-variable-name)

I need to write the output of my code, which generates some 200 files of 50k*4. I want to know if i can write each individual file with a different name in my working directory. Right now the maximum i can do is to save one file by using the code :

`write.table(filename,"name.csv")` or `write.csv()`.

On saving if the file with the same name exists, throw a warning and save it with a different name. Is there a way??

Edited : some code is here. Each time a file is generated, i want to write it with a unique name.

```
      affy.data = ReadAffy()
      for(i in 1: length(affy.data))
      {

       eset.mas5 = mas5(affy.data[,i])

    ## getting the expression matrix (probesets/genes in rows, chips in columns).
    exprSet.nologs = exprs(eset.mas5)

    ## At this time let's log-transform the expression values to get a more normal distribution. 
    ## We have to remember we've done this when we calculate ratios. Logarithms can use any
    ## base, but base 2 is easiest when transforming ratios, since transformed 2-fold
    ## ratios up or down will be +1 or -1. As a result, we'll do all logs with base
    ## 2 to keep thing simplest.
    #exprSet = log(exprSet.nologs, 2)


    ## While we're doing Affymetrix-specific preprocessing, let's calculate an Absent/Present call for each probeset.
    # Run the Affy A/P call algorithm on the CEL files we processed above
    data.mas5calls = mas5calls(affy.data[,i])

    # Get the actual A/P calls
    data.mas5calls.calls = exprs(data.mas5calls)

    ## Getting pvalue
    pvalue <- assayData(data.mas5calls)[["se.exprs"]]

    ## Combining data
    data.full <- cbind(exprSet.nologs,data.mas5calls.calls,pvalue)
    colnames(data.full) <- c("VALUE","ABS_CALL","DETECTION P-VALUE")
    print(head(data.full,20))
    write.table(data.full, file="1.txt", quote=F, sep="\t")
    }
```

Comment: Can you clue us in to which R objects you are writing?  We could generate a unique file name for each object, and then use that as a filename.

Comment: say it as `data.full` . do you mean this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(i in 1:length(affy.data)) {
    ...
    write.table(data.full, file=paste0(i,".txt"), quote=F, sep="\t")
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. If there is a file already named (any i=1,2,3  so on) , then ??

Comment: Don't name your files like that, it's just example. You can set whatever file name you want like this: `paste0("NewFileName_",i,".txt")`